# Split text file into multiline string array using Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, split, srt

I need to split an .srt file text like

```
1
00:02:10,437 --> 00:02:11,598
Day one, Greenie.

2
00:02:11,757 --> 00:02:12,838
Rise and shine.

3
00:02:14,357 --> 00:02:16,041
He looks like
a slopper to me.
```

split into multi-line string array, each string has at least 3 lines, 
one for the number, one for the time, and one or more for the text of the subtitles

can you help?

Answer (score 0):

```
\n{2,}
```

Split by this and you have your result.

Comment: This answer is ... short :-).

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi didnt get you?